# Security Breach using AWS Lambda functions saving files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html,

I have to provide the following information as part of the payload in order to save a file onto S3 using Lambda functions.

```
"Records":[  
  {  
     "eventVersion":"2.0",
     "eventSource":"aws:s3",
     "awsRegion":"us-west-2",
     "eventTime":"1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
     "eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put",
     "userIdentity":{  
        "principalId":"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE"
     },
     "requestParameters":{  
        "sourceIPAddress":"127.0.0.1"
     },
     "responseElements":{  
        "x-amz-request-id":"C3D13FE58DE4C810",
        "x-amz-id-2":"FMyUVURIY8/IgAtTv8xRjskZQpcIZ9KG4V5Wp6S7S/JRWeUWerMUE5JgHvANOjpD"
     },
     "s3":{  
        "s3SchemaVersion":"1.0",
        "configurationId":"testConfigRule",
        "bucket":{  
           "name":"sourcebucket",
           "ownerIdentity":{  
              "principalId":"A3NL1KOZZKExample"
           },
           "arn":"arn:aws:s3:::sourcebucket"
        },
        "object":{  
           "key":"HappyFace.jpg",
           "size":1024,
           "eTag":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
           "versionId":"096fKKXTRTtl3on89fVO.nfljtsv6qko"
        }
     }
  }
]
```

But if I inject the following information for every API call accessing to S3 / whether it be GET or POST, I feel like this is too much information for users to know. What is the "right" way of doing this?

Comment: The Json that you included in your question is for simulating an S3 event (ObjectCreated). You can create your own interface with the parameters that you require if you do not need to be invoked by S3 when a ObjectCreate event happens.

Comment: What about thing like "principalId" or "sourceIPAddress" or maybe just the name of the bucket. Is it possible to abstract those completely away from users? Do corporates that use Lambda actually reveal this kind of info in their payload?

Comment: You are misunderstanding. The Json that you posted comes from AWS S3 as the event payload. You don't create it unless you are trying to emulate an S3 event. You can create any interface you want and the backend code, you do not have to copy AWS.

Comment: I see what you mean now! But what I still don't understand is this flow. User calls endpoint -> s3 sends notification to lambda -> lambda does its logic and saves to S3 -> user receives success message. In this flow, what is the "endpoint" that user needs to hit? Is it s3 bucket? If so, where can I find that..?

Comment: The article that you referenced shows how to receive an event at a Lambda function when a new object is created in a bucket and do some processing on that object. The end user does not call your Lambda function directly.